# How to throw and catch a BehaviorSubject Observable error

Tags: angular

I have an observable

```
bs = new BehaviorSubject<BS>(new BS());

onObsChange(): Observable<BS> {
    return this.bs.asObservable();
}
```

then I subscribe to the observable

```
this.sessionService.onBSChange().subscribe(
            data => self.user = data.user,
            error => console.log(error)
        );
```

I can get data in the subscription callback but don't know how to catch or throw errors with observables/behavior subjects.

```
this.bs.next(newValue);     // data => ...
```

How can I throw an error with observable bs that will be caught in the onBSChange() subscription?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `error` on the subject:

```
this.bs.error(err);
```

Comment: I was doing this from a catch block of a Promise and it causes an 'unhandled error' error